# Solr in-place live upgrade 3.1 to 3.5

Tags: solr

What it takes to upgrade Solr instance (the exact to/from versions are 3.1 - 3.5)?
Is it possible to do an in-place upgrade and avoid service interruption?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

To avoid *any* service interruption, I would recommend constructing a brand new Solr instance, starting it on a different server (or a different port on the same server), populating the index, and then switching the server/port that the production client sends its queries to. Then you can take the old Solr instance offline, start a new instance of the new Solr config on the old server/port and switch the client back.

Comment: Thanks, Ansari. Could you please point me to the documentation where Solr upgrade options are explained? I'd like to know what variants other than creating a new instance there are and their requirements in terms of service availability during the upgrade.